# How do I resolve the error: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

I am receiving the error "5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64" when attempting to launch my React Native project in Xcode. I am using a MacBook Pro, chip Apple M1 and macOS Monterey v 12.2.1. Has anyone had this issue before and managed to resolve it? Can you please help? I have tried other fixes but these failed to work. Below is my podFile:

[image]

Error log:

duplicate symbol '_bridgeRef' in:
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)

duplicate symbol '_fsQueue' in:
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)

duplicate symbol '_fsQueue' in:
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blob-util/libreact-native-blob-util.a(ReactNativeBlobUtil.o)

/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlob.o)

....
duplicate symbol '_fileStreams' in:
/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobFS.o)

/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/rn-fetch-blob/librn-fetch-blob.a(RNFetchBlobNetwork.o)

ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I receive the below error if I uninstall rn-fetch-blob, run pod install and then run the app in Xcode:

[image]
[image]

I need the RNFetchBlob package since I am using it in my code or is there something else I can use as the equivalent? Is react-native-blob-util the equivalent? Can someone help please?

Comment: Please add the exact error log.

Comment: Error logs added. Thanks

Comment: Actually seeing the above undefined symbol errors after running pod install. Can someone help please?

Comment: `cd ios && cd rm -rf Pods` then do `pod install`

Comment: By the way, have you recently added any package? that might have caused this issue, if so check the setup instructions of that package, you might have missed something..

Comment: Same error after removing pods and installing again. I did not add any packages. I am just moving my project from my old MacBook to my new one. The old MacBook did not have M1 chip. I had to use Rosetta in the terminal in my new MacBook

Comment: Yes, you need to open XCode using Rossetta. The error will go..

Comment: Ok, so now I'm getting the initial error now 'ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Answer (score 1):

Same issue but I found this on homebrew github: https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4794

Adding '-Wl,-ld_classic' in "Other Linker Flags" worked for me.

[image]

Comment: That flag worked for me. Using RN 0.71.6

Answer (score 0):

Go to xcode select pods under Targets click on react-native-fetch-blob and
[select no common block from yes to no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7u8.png)

repeat this process for react-native-blob-utils